# Merge two maps only at the boundaries with python code

Tags: merge, python-3

[image]I have two maps one is normal cluster map and other is a grid map. I want that only at the boundaries the cluster map should follow grid map. Refer to the image, map in violet is my cluster map and map in green is my grid map. In this image grid map is on the outer part(1) but at some points grid map is on the inner part(2).

I am trying to do it in python using Geopandas but not getting any answer.The logic I am thinking is as follows The places where Grid map is on outer side I will take union and the places at which grid map is on inner side I will take intersection but i am not getting the condition logic .

[image]

Help me with a python code.

[image]

Comment: "*trying to do it in python using Geopandas but not getting any answer*" please show us a minimal example of your code and describe what happens when you run it, including any errors (as text, not screenshots).

Comment: I don't get what your end result needs to look like. Maybe if you draw a sketch of what you want as a result onto your image we could help you better.

Comment: There are two cases  - 1. Green grids are on outer side(which can be seen ) . 2. green grids are on inner side(can't be seen because violet map covers them) . we wan't that at every point the violet boundary should stretch(in case 1) or compress(in case 2) such that at the boundary we will have violet coloured grids instead of green color grid @til_b

Comment: I don't have the code @user2856 . please read previous comment to clarify the problem in better way